# Android Studio XML tags sorting

Tags: android-studio

After update to AS 3.5 I can't properly use reformat code feature in xml files.
Auto reformat code not only sort attributes inside tags, but also moves tags in a file. So some elements get wrong visibility because of wrong order.
I couldn't find anything related in Settings -> Editor -> Code Style

Comment: It's a common issue with the 3.5 upgrade. Check the accepted answer on the linked duplicate.

Comment: @MikeM. That what I couldn't find. Thx!